# Visual Studio 2010 проблемма с автоинкрементарным полем

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

Здравствуйте! Помогите решить проблемму. Создал проект на `Visual Studio 2010`. Подключился к базе MS SQL Server 2008 (визуальными средствами первого), но при добавлении записи в таблицы БД, не происходит автоматического увеличения автоинкрементарных(ключевых) полей. То есть Visual отправляет в ключевом поле NULL, а в базе автоматом оно не увеличивается, из за чего происходит ошибка. Как это решить? В интернете не нашел.

Comment: А база данных случайно ошибку не выдает, что было в поле отправлено NULL?

Comment: нет.. база не выдает, с самой базой все хорошо, и установлена ровно и работает. Данные даже не успевают записаться, именно в Студии что то, потому что, чтобы данные попали в базу там нужно функцию Адаптера запустить, а ошибка происходит когда просто на другую строчку переходишь.

Comment: Для верности, попробуйте в `SQl Server Management Studio` сделать запрос  

    isert into tablename (pole1, pole2) values ('value1', 2)  

И посмотрите, ставится новое значение или нет. Если нет, то ошибка НЕ в программном коде. Тогда посмотрите на свойства таблицы.

Answer (score 1):

Такая ошибка часто возникает если не установлен PK (Primary Key) у таблицы. Проверьте.
**UPDATE:**
Вы явно передате `null` или нет? Проблема скорее всего в том, что когда у поля стоит `Identity`, то не нужно передавать какое либо значение для ключевого поля, добавляете только значения для других полей. Например, таблица с полями: `ID` `(PK, Identity)`, `name`. То запрос нужно делать такой:

```
 INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable(name) VALUES('value');
```

Comment: В таблице (MS SQL Server) примари код стоит, и автоинкремент есть.

Comment: Покажите лучше запрос который выполняет добавление в БД.

Comment: insert into dbo.postavil(recv_post, cont_post) values ('value1', 'value2')
сделал в поля (id, recv_post, cont_post) такую запись (1,value1,value2)
тоесть запрос через средства самого MS SQL, добавляет запись и автоинкремент срабатывает, ошибка при работе именно из приложения просто пишу на С# язык для меня новый

Comment: Проблема ясна. Теперь покажите свой код на C#.

Comment: Вот именно кода нет ... подключаюсь через визуальные средства. Думаю если бы отправлял чисто SQL запрос можно было бы просто пропустить в Insert поле id  и вставка осуществилась бы. а здесь ума не приложу где галочку не поставил. 
И еще вопрос попутно: Если сделать просто SQL запрос на выборку данных как достать из полученной записи отдельно поля? например для расчета суммы товара по цене за штуку и его количеству.